# Trigonometry sine and cos problem

Tags: trigonometry

> Knowing that
>   $$
>  \sin a - \sin b = \frac{1}{2}
>  \quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad
>  \cos a + \cos b = \frac{3}{2}
> $$
>   calculate $\cos (a+b)$.

I have tried various methods but I can't seem to get to a result , I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you calculate $\cos(a-b)?$

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:**

Square both sides of each equation and add the results up.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept the answer as soon as I can ( 10 more minutes to minimum time..)

Answer (score 5):

Let $b=-c$, $P=e^{ia}$ and $Q=e^{ic}$. Then you know that $P+Q = \frac{3+i}{2}$ and you have to find the cosine of the angle $\theta$ between $P$ and $Q$. Since the cosine theorem gives:
$$ \| P+Q \|^2 = \|P\|^2 + \|Q\|^2 + 2 \|P\|\|Q\|\cos\theta $$
we just have:
$$ \cos\theta = \frac{\left\|\frac{3+i}{2}\right\|^2-2}{2} = \frac{\frac{10}{4}-2}{2} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}.$$

Comment: This is the definition of "overkill". Though, +1: I would have never thought about doing that.

Comment: Gosh... cool...

Answer (score 4):

Notice, $$\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(2\cos a\cos b-2\sin a\sin b)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}((\cos a+\cos b)^2-\cos^2 a-\cos^2 b+(\sin a-\sin b)^2-\sin^2 a-\sin^2 b)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-(\cos^2a+\sin^2 a)-(\cos^2 b+\sin^2 b)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{10}{4}-1-1\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)$$ $$=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{4}}$$